# How to Include Issue History in Excel Export of Mantis Bugs. MantisBT v1.2.12

Tags: mantis

Is there a plugin or via code to include **Issue History** while exporting **Mantis bugs** in Excel?

Else, is there a way to download **Issue History** along with the respective Mantis ID in MS Excel?

MantisBT Version 1.2.12

Schema Version 183

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt seem like there is out of the box way, but you could try the **[Query plugin](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=14633)**. It allows you to create custom queries and export them into Excel.

You can download it here:
http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=14633